# How to change my old sha1 passwords to sha256 or Bcrypt values in database field

Tags: php, codeigniter, sha1, bcrypt

I have a database of data in which password column uses sha1 values. I am planning to update my encryption method to Bcrypt or sha256. Would like to get a script which will update all the sha1 passwords to sha256 or Bcrypt values. Many thanks

Example:
if my password is hari

`sha1` gives

```
46ebaaa2b80c7a3459b80353e085aaeed5aff2ff
```

`sha256` gives

```
f7b3781c5eafc2779a96bae2e4875a83ecce46f198e9f81916521d9d218c7da7
```

I what to change all sha1 to sha256

Comment: You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead of trying to roll your own hashing algorithm. Also, you can't update the passwords yourself since you only have hashes and not the real passwords. I would suggest adding a column in your table: `needs_rehash`. If that is set to true when a user logs in, then check against the current sha1-hash, rehash the password using password_hash() and set the column `needs_rehash` to false.

Comment: You'll have a chance to rehash the users' passwords the next time they login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change hash values as **Hash operation is not reversible**. That is you can convert plain text into hash value but not the reverse. 
So, a better idea would be to make a different table for sha256 passwords. And keep porting your users to the other tables when the log in next time. 
I.e., the next time a user logins, check of the password is correct from the existing table. If the user is found to be correct, then rehash the password using sha256 and save it to another(new) table. In this way eventually, when user logins you can port them to more safer sha256 hashed passwords. 
Once a user is ported, you can remove their entries from the older table(either at that very moment / later by any batch script).

Now comes how to handle login. It will be a 2 step process till all users are ported. 
1. First check in the newer table. If found fine, go ahead with it.
2. Else check in the older table.

Comment: There's no need to create a new table. Just add a column to the existing table that says if the password needs rehashing or not and if it does, then, on a successful log in, just hash the password correctly and update the password hash in the DB and set the "needs rehash"-flag to false.

Comment: Yes, that can also be a solution. Different way to do the same thing. But your solution is better.

Comment: In this case, having two tables can create a lot of issues. Example: You want to joint the user table for some reason, which table should you join? You can't join the new, since not all users might exist in that. You can't join the old, since there might be updated data in the new table. Also, when a user logs in, you will need to first check the new table, and if the user doesn't exist there, you need to get the user from the old table. That seems pretty unnecessary since you can solve it by simply adding an extra column in the existing table.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson : True. That's why I said your solution is better. I understood the advantages once you proposed the solution.

Answer (score 3):

A lot have been said in other answer or comments.

Basically, you cannot simply move from a hashing value to another hashing value corresponding to the initial value. A hash function is a one-way function.

But fear not, there is hope! Here is an approach which will allow you to:

- Add a new password hashing algorithm
- Avoid resetting all your users' password
- Handle legacy password hashing algorithm
- Protect the legacy password with the new hashing algorithm right now

---

## Choosing the hashing function

This is important. Please read carefully.

For password storage, you should **not** use any (cryptographic) hashing function like SHA1, SHA2 or even SHA3 (Keccak). The main reason is that they are fast. Too fast. Which is not something you should thrive for with password hashing. [More information](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28).

Also they don't handle salting, which mean you will need to do this manually, which mean you have higher chance of messing it up.

For password storage, you need a **password hashing function** made for this express purpose. You have several well known function : PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt or Argon2.

These function can handle a salt and are slow (and the performance is tunable by parameters).

Now since you are using PHP, this is even simpler for you. The [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function gives you a nice and working BCrypt right of the bat. Use it!

It even supports Argon2 if you are using PHP 7.2+. But stick to BCrypt for now. It's simpler and battle-tested.

The main issue you'll have with BCrypt is configuring its parameter: the `cost` value. It directly influence the time it takes to compute a single hash.

Basically, it depends on your server. So you'll need to make some test here, starting with a default cost of 10 and going up until it takes between 700ms ~ 1s to compute the hash.

I made [this handy PHP script](https://gist.github.com/Indigo744/24062e07477e937a279bc97b378c3402) some times ago to help me in this task. I also made one for [for Argon2](https://gist.github.com/Indigo744/e92356282eb808b94d08d9cc6e37884c) but as you can see it's more complex.

Also, never supply your own salt. Let the function handle this for you (even if you *think* you can do better).

---

## Implement the new password hashing algorithm

As said in some comments, your best approach is to add a new boolean column `legacy_pwd`, initialized to true.

**EDIT** : *don't forget of course to update your table definition regarding the column size*. SHA1 digest has a size of 40 hex chars (160 bits), whereas BCrypt digest has a size of 60 chars.

Furthermore, in order to protect right now your existing customer password, I suggest you apply the new hashing function (BCrypt) to the `password` column.

When a user try to log in with its username/password, you first check the `legacy_pwd`.

**If `legacy_pwd` is true**, take `bcrypt(sha1("plain_text_pwd"))` and compare it to the one store in the DB. If it matches, store `bcrypt("plain_text_pwd")`, set `legacy_pwd` to false and log the user in.

**If `legacy_pwd` is false**, simply take `bcrypt("plain_text_pwd")` and compare it to the one store in the DB. If it matches, log the user in.

---

## Follow-up and cleaning

Regularly, you'll need to check if `legacy_pwd` has any `true` value remaining. If not (all users have migrated), you can delete the column and delete the code handling the legacy password.